# Replacing a specific element from a JSON object stored as string in Hive

Tags: hive

I have a hive table and one of the columns is having a string data type and it actually stores a json object.

I am trying to fire a SELECT on that table but I want to replace only one of the elements in the JSON. For example, lets say for a specific hive row the value of the column holding JSON is:-

```
{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       "sonoo",   
        "salary":     56000,   
        "married":    true  
    }  
}
```

Now I want to replace value of the element $.employee.name (the current value is "sonoo") with null(or blank etc). So the select statement should return the following

```
 {  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       null,   
        "salary":     56000,   
        "married":    true  
    }  
}
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to parse all JSON tuple and re-assemble JSON again, then this is the solution using sing `regex_replace`:

```
 with your_data as (
select stack (1,
'{  
    "employee": {  
        "name":       "sonoo",   
        "salary":     56000,   
        "married":    true  
    }  
}') as json_str
) --use you_table instead of this


 select regexp_replace(json_str,'(\\"employee\\":\\s*\\{\\s*\\"name\\":\\s*)(\\".*\\")([\\S\\s]*)','$1null$3') as json_str
  from your_data s;
```

Result:

```
OK
{
    "employee": {
        "name":       null,
        "salary":     56000,
        "married":    true
    }
}
Time taken: 0.074 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

**First group** in the regex describes everything before value to be replaced:

`(\\"employee\\":\\s*\\{\\s*\\"name\\":\\s*)` - means:

`\\"employee\\":` - "employee": literally,

`\\s*` -  any number of spaces

`\\{` - { character

`\\s*` -  any number of spaces

`\\"name\\":` - "name":

`\\s*` -  any number of spaces

Why the first group is described in such details including employee key? To make sure we will replace only name value in the employee nested structure, not the other name, which can be in some other nested structure.

**Secong group** is the string in double-quotes to be replaced: `(\\".*\\")`

**Third group** is everething else after the Second group: `([\\S\\s]*)` - any number of space or non-space characters. If the JSON does not contain newlines \n, then simply (.*) may work, test it yourself

So, the regexp matches the whole JSON, consisting of three groups. And you replacing it with `'$1null$3'` - **First group**, **null** and **Third group** concatenated together. In other words, **Second group** is replaced with **null**, everything else as is.

Comment: it makes lot of assumptions about the sequence of values. Sequence could be in any order, that shouldn't matter, and there could be additional key value pairs at each level that we don't care about. Basically the input is a precise json path and we need to surgically just tweak value for the given key in the given path, so it's not that straightforward.

Comment: @Dhiraj yep. agree. the assumption is that name is first in the employee struct.

Comment: i am basically looking for a non-trivial solution, the simple example I provided was only for simplifying asking a question here, but in case of my problem, exact path of key value pair that i am trying to remove could be pretty deep in the json,  it's not really a json table as shown in this simple example